# Edit in Photoshop not getting changes from LR

Tags: lightroom, raw, workflow

My general flow has always been - do most work in LR and then complicated layer issues I deal with in PS...

With the current LR/PS CC When I choose "Edit in Photoshop CC2017" it simply opens the ORIGINAL unedited RAW file, not a tiff or PSD with the modifications I have made in LR.

I do NOT get a choice of "Open Original" "Open with edits" etc... that I used to get... I don't know when this started happening, but it USED to give me options

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Although it's saying it's opening as a RAW on the photoshop tabs are the modifications appearing in Photoshop? As it doesn't usually appear as a TIF or PSD until you save.

Comment: To give more info - it would appear that SOME edits are making the trip...  I'm working on a longer exposure starfield picture so I have the Noise Reduction settings pretty high in LR... That Noise reduction isn't showing in Photoshop, while things like WB and Exposure edits are going across.

Comment: I also do not get the choice of "Edit a Copy with Lightroom adjustments" "Edit Original" "Edit a Copy" that I USED to get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gentleman over on Photography-on-the-net helped me work through the issue....  That thread is here: http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?p=18435470

TIL:

1) When LR shows images resized in the "viewing area", it lies sometimes.

2) The highres, full sized images ARE the same.

3) The exported smaller image despite being exported the SAME way, isn't necessarily going to be the same.

4) There are still some kind, patient individuals in the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to try "Open with Additional External Editor" (Crtl+Alt+E). This must give you the option to choose from dialog what to be resolution, colours space and so on.

Other possible way is to reset the current settings of Lightroom, restart the software and try again.